# Do something with old close vote reasons

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Recently, I found a couple of questions with closure reasons that are no longer available to 3k+ users today, case in point [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025959/how-can-i-make-a-basic-php-scoreboard)'s "not constructive" close reason (which I believe would now be the "Too Broad" closure reason). Should we remove these old close reasons and remap them to new reasons, or should we just bring them back to flagging and close voting?

Comment: What's the point in revising history?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regular users only have a limited number of votes per day and they would be better spent on questions that need to be closed. Plus it also uses up another (probably even more precious) resource: time. Additionally, I think reopening and closing like this makes the history of the post significantly more confusing to read.

There is extremely little to be gained by switching the close reason. If it becomes relevant (say for example someone had an old question they wanted reopened that was closed for such a reason), then the far more effective action is to **leave a comment** explaining what they need to change to fix the question. This, unlike reopening/closing, will actually notify OP.

---

Perhaps not coincidentally, this also applies to cases where a user makes edits and invalidates the close reason but didn't fix the question enough for it to be reopened.